# Discrepancy in file size on disk and ls output

Tags: mac, shell-script, ls

I have a script that checks for gzipped file sizes greater than 1MB and outputs files along with their sizes as a report.

This is the code:

```
myReport=`ls -ltrh "$somePath" | egrep '\.gz$' |  awk '{print $9,"=>",$5}'`
# Count files that exceed 1MB
oversizeFiles=`find "$somePath" -maxdepth 1  -size +1M -iname "*.gz" -print0 | xargs -0 ls -lh | wc -l`

 if [ $oversizeFiles -eq 0 ];then
    status="PASS"

 else
     status="CHECK FAILED. FOUND FILES GREATER THAN 1MB"
 fi

echo -e $status"\n"$myReport
```

The problem is that ls command outputs the files sizes as 1.0MB in the report but the status is "FAIL" as "$oversizeFiles" variable's value is 2. I checked the file sizes on disk and 2 files are 1.1MB. 
Why this discrepancy? How should I modify the script so that I can generate an accurate report?

BTW, I'm on a Mac.

Here is what man page for "find" says on my Mac OSX:

```
-size n[ckMGTP]
True if the file's size, rounded up, in 512-byte blocks is n.  
If n is followed by a c,then the primary is true if the file's size is n bytes (characters).  
Similarly if n is followed by a scale indicator then the file's size is compared to n scaled as:  

 k       kilobytes (1024 bytes)
 M       megabytes (1024 kilobytes)
 G       gigabytes (1024 megabytes)
 T       terabytes (1024 gigabytes)
 P       petabytes (1024 terabytes)
```

Answer (score 2):

In `find`, `M` actually refers to mebibytes, not megabytes.

```
find -size +1M
```

will find all files greater than 1,048,576 bytes.

To find all files greater than 1.0 MB (1,000,000 bytes), use this instead:

```
find -size +1000000c
```

Comment: Actually, 1048065 or more bytes, since the size rounded up to the next full 512 byte block.

Comment: `ls` considers files to be `1.0M` up to 1101004 bytes, and that is significantly more (51,7KiB) than `find`'s minimum required size of 1048065.

Comment: @DanielBeck: I was was wrong about "greater or equal", but - at least on Ubuntu - there appears to be no rounding. I checked: `find -size 1048574c` finds a file of 1048575 bytes and `find -size 1M` finds a file of 1048577 bytes. Regarding your second comment, I'm not sure *I checked the file sizes on disk...* refers to `ls`.

Comment: This Q is about OS X/BSD `find`. There's a difference in how numerical arguments are intepreted IIRC: *All primaries which take a numeric argument allow the number to be preceded by a plus sign (+) or a minus sign (-).  A preceding plus sign **means more than n**, a preceding minus sign means **less than n** and neither means **exactly n**.*. `man find` also states regarding `-size`: *True if the file's size, rounded up, in 512-byte blocks is n.  If n is followed by a c, then the primary is true if the file's size is n bytes (characters).*. 2nd cmt just indicates how much these values overlap.